# Solving Non-Linear First order ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The equation is:
$$\frac{dx}{dt} = \beta + {\alpha}x{(1 - \frac{x}{\kappa})} - x(\mu + \nu + \delta)$$

$\beta, \alpha, \kappa, \mu, \nu, \delta$ are all constants.
I am trying to solve this differential equation.

I understand that this is a non-linear, first order differential equation, however it is non-separable due to the logistic component. 
I don't think it is exact either so I don't know what to do now.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Am I right to say that it takes the form of a Riccati differential equation if the logistic component is expanded out? Is there a technique used to solve Riccati differential equations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation is nonlinear, but it *is* separable, as it has the form
$$
\frac{\text{d} x}{\text{d} t} = f(x).
$$
Therefore, all you have to do is to solve the equation
$$
\int^x \frac{1}{f(\hat{x})}\text{d}\hat{x} = t + t_0
$$
for $x$. You will obtain something of the form
$$
x(t) = c_1 + c_2 \,\text{tanh} \left(c_3(t+t_0)\right),
$$
where $c_1,c_2,c_3$ are constants depending on the model parameters $\alpha,\beta,\delta,\kappa,\mu,\nu$.